# nested loop in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of words in `l` that if any of it exists in the first index of each tuple in l2, remove the entire tuple.

my code:

```
l = ['hi', 'thanks', 'thank', 'bye', 'ok', 'yes', 'okay']
l2 = [('hi how are u', 'doing great'), ('looking for me', 'please hold')]
l3 = [k for k in l2 if not any(i in k[0] for i in l) ]
```

somehow the code does not work and i get back an empty list for l3.

I want

```
l3 = [('looking for me', 'please hold')]
```

Comment: lo**ok**ing for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split `k[0]` to get a list of words:

```
[k for k in l2 if not any(i in k[0].split() for i in l)]
```

This way it checks if `i` matches a word exactly.

It could also be interpreted as if `k[0]` does not starts with any of `l`, then you can do this:

```
[k for k in l2 if not k[0].startswith(tuple(l))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sets make membership testing easy.  Use a function to filter your list.

```
import operator
first = operator.itemgetter(0

l = ['hi', 'thanks', 'thank', 'bye', 'ok', 'yes', 'okay']
l2 = [('hi how are u', 'doing great'), ('looking for me', 'please hold')]

def foo(t, l = set(l)):
    t = set(first(t).split())
    return bool(l & t)

l3 = [thing for thing in l2 if not foo(thing)]
```